# Access Matlab runtime in a conda environment

Tags: python, python-3.x, matlab, anaconda, conda

I have a standalone matlab exe which I can run on my laptop with the matlab runtime. I can run it from python and get the output with `subprocess.check_output`. Everything works fine!

The problem is that I need to run the python script inside a conda environment. I have the following error:

[image]

how can I make it accessible from the conda environment?

Comment: How does the exe file find the Matlab Runtime outside of a conda environment?

Comment: I don't know, I just installed the Matlab runtime and everything works... Of course before the matlab runtime installation I had the same error running the exe outside of a conda environment.

Comment: I presume that the Conda environment changes the PATH environment variable. Try to read that value from your Python script, and compare inside/outside Conda.

Comment: Is it possible the matlab engine was not installed in your conda environment but within your other python interpreter? There's a post here about running matlab with conda: https://groups.google.com/a/continuum.io/forum/#!topic/anaconda/aaUAMIwlWRc

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've solved my problem by adding the runtime in the PATH.

```
import os
os.environ['PATH'] = "C:\\Program Files\\MATLAB\\MATLAB Runtime\\v91\\;C:\\Program Files\\MATLAB\\MATLAB Runtime\\v91\\bin;"+os.environ['PATH']
```